# Why watch doesn't invoke when I usePromise?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm using `@vue/composition-api` and usePromise from [vue-composable](https://github.com/pikax/vue-composable).

I watch on computed value that return from a promise. the promise is resolve after 12000ms.

For the first time the `computed` and `watch` are invoked, but after 12000ms none of them is invoke. so the watch callback doesn't work.  even the api.result is changed.

I can see that value changed in the template by printing: `{{items}}`.

How to solve this unexpected behavior? how to call the watch callback when the value change?

here is the output:

```
 in computed
 in watch
```

expected:

```
     in computed
     in watch
     in computed <-- data is resolved the api.result changed (has new value).
     in watch <--- same.
```

The code:

```
  setup() {

    function timeout(ms) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    const api = usePromise(() => Promise.all([timeout(12000).then(() => ({ some: 'data'}))]));

    const items = computed(() => {
      console.log('in computed');
      return api.result;
    });

    watch(items, (v) => {
      console.log('in watch');
    })

    api.exec();
    return { items }
```

This is works:

```
  watch(api.result, (v) => {
    console.log('in watch api.result');
  })
```

But why computed doesn't work? how make it recalculate so the watch on computed will work?

[The code on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-shadow-n066h)

Comment: I see you closed the issue on https://github.com/pikax/vue-composable/issues/188 - care to answer your own question below?